# Have a column "num_posts" or querying the database

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a forum. A small forum with maybe 100 visitors a day.

Would the best way be to store the number of posts a topic has by just creating a column `num_posts` and each time a user makes a post in that topic I just increase that number by one. And the other way when a user deletes a post. Or just make a query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM posts 
WHERE topic_id = thetopicid
```

I prefer the second. But off course I guess it affect performance. But how much? Is this bad practice?

Comment: option B install one of the many existing forum scripts?

Comment: its much more fun making your own plus you learn

Comment: For 100 visitors a day I would choose `COUNT(*)` and maybe `VIEW` in database.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by view?

Comment: apprentice chefs chop onions

Answer (score 1):

Use `count(*)`.  Having that extra column requires you to maintain it yourself, i.e. update on new and deleted posts.  You need to add something extra to do this which definitely requires extra resource, whereas using `count(*)` you are using something already built in to DMBS.

Comment: yes thats what i like. i dont have to worry about if a user deletes a topic for example. then i have to count how many posts that topic has and then update the num_posts column in the forum table

Comment: Deleting topics shouldn't be an issue. If you used a column, it would be in the `topics` table. So if the topic is deleted, the `num_posts` column goes with it.